# How to write JSON to Realm in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, realm

I can't find information how to write my `JSON` data to my `Realm DB` in `Swift`.

I have class:

```
class News: Object {
    dynamic var newsID: String = ""
    dynamic var newsTitle: String = ""
    dynamic var newsFullText: String = ""
    dynamic var newsAutor: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCommentCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsSeenCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsDate: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCategory: String = ""
}
```

In here I take `JSON` from server:

```
func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [News] {

    do {
        let temp: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let myNSData = temp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myNSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        let jsonNews = jsonResult["posts"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonnewes in jsonNews {
            let newsJson = News()
            newsJson.newsTitle = jsonnewes["post_title"] as! String
            newsJson.newsAutor = jsonnewes["author_name"] as! String
            newsJson.newsFullText = jsonnewes["full_text"] as! String
            newsJson.newsID = jsonnewes["id"] as! String
            newsJson.newsCategory = jsonnewes["menu_category_name"] as! String
            newsJson.newsDate = jsonnewes["create_date"] as! String
            newsJson.newsSeenCount = jsonnewes["review"] as! String
            newsJson.newsCommentCount = jsonnewes["comment_count"] as! String
            newsItems.append(newsJson)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return newsItems
}
```

And how to write my data to `Realm DB`?

Comment: Did you even read the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)? write object to realm db is very easy

Comment: Yes of course. I know that I can write by  try! realm.write {
  let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
  realm.create(City.self, value: json, update: true)
} but it is not help to me

Comment: Collect your `newsJson` in an array (say `newsObjects`) and then call `realm.add(newsObjects)` to add them all to Realm.

Comment: @Zhan after you created your array of `News` you can loop through it and do a `realm.add(news)`, means after your `parseJSONData ` then only add it

Comment: My serialization is correct?

Comment: Maybe but it have unwrapped force `String` type, so if one key-value is nil your app will crash, try `if let id = jsonnewes["id"] as? String {....}` is better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this :

```
func insertOrUpdate(news: News) {
    try! realm.write({
            realm.add(news)
        })
}
```

but it is better you create a model without inherit from object :

```
class News {
   var newsID: String = ""
   var newsTitle: String = ""
   var newsFullText: String = ""
   var newsAutor: String = ""
   var newsCommentCount: String = ""
   var newsSeenCount: String = ""
   var newsDate: String = ""
   var newsCategory: String = ""
}



class NewsRealm: Object {
    dynamic var newsID: String = ""
    dynamic var newsTitle: String = ""
    dynamic var newsFullText: String = ""
    dynamic var newsAutor: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCommentCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsSeenCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsDate: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCategory: String = ""
}
```

then after parse json you call insertOrUpdate and map data with NewsRealm :

```
func insertOrUpdate(news: News) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write({
        let newsRealm = NewsRealm()
        newsRealm.newsTitle = news.newsTitle
        newsRealm.newsAutor = news.newsAutor
        newsRealm.newsFullText = news.newsFullText
        .
        .
        .
        realm.add(newsRealm)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for update filed . you should define method in newsRealm for primary key:

```
class NewsRealm: Object {
    dynamic var newsID: String = ""
    dynamic var newsTitle: String = ""
    dynamic var newsFullText: String = ""
    dynamic var newsAutor: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCommentCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsSeenCount: String = ""
    dynamic var newsDate: String = ""
    dynamic var newsCategory: String = ""

      override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "newsID"
      }
}
```

and then for update :

```
func insertOrUpdate(news: News) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write({
        let newsRealm = NewsRealm()
        newsRealm.newsTitle = news.newsTitle
        newsRealm.newsAutor = news.newsAutor
        newsRealm.newsFullText = news.newsFullText
        .
        .
        .
        realm.add(newsRealm, update: true)            })

}
```

if a new filed so your object add into database but there are in database your object be update .

sorry for my english ;)

Comment: How does this answer differ from your other answer? Which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me, you shouldn't create class News and NewsRealm, just one:

```
  import SwiftyJSON

    class News: Object {
       @objc dynamic var newsID: String?
       @objc dynamic var newsTitle: String?

     convenience init(value: JSON) {
       self.init()
       for (key, value) in value {
          switch key {
           case "newsID":
              self.newsID = value.stringValue
           case "newsTitle":
              self.newsTitle = value.stringValue
           }
        }
      }
     }
```

Somwhere in code

```
    let model = News(value: jsonObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Swift 5** and **RealmSwift v10.20.0**

Try setting a primary key to your News class with this code:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "newsID"
}
```

Then you can parse and save the JSON this way:

```
do {
    try! realm.write {
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        realm.create(News.self, value: json, update: .modified)
    }
} catch {
    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Or, if your class doesn't have a primary key, you can code this instead:

```
    realm.create(News.self, value: json, update: .error)
```