# Realm Document to Swift Object using Codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

I had performance issues due to converting a `Document` to a Swift Object doing something like `document["property"]??.doubleValue` for each property and property of embedded Documents. So I now figured out the best way to do this would probably be the `Decodable`. So I tried:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
            //let resultDocuments = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultDocuments, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let model = try decoder.decode(Model, from: resultDocuments)
            //print(model)
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
```

Which fails to compile due to *Cannot convert value of type 'Document' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Optional>') to expected argument type 'Data'*

---

More context

From an aggregate call I receive a `Document` from a

```swift
// collection was initialised from a Realm database
let resultDocuments = try await collection.aggregate(pipeline: somePipeline)
```

where the result is of type `Document`:

```swift
/// A Dictionary object representing a `BSON` document.
public typealias Document = Dictionary<String, AnyBSON?>
```

The result looks like this:

```swift
[[
"example": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.double(1096.5171548657413)),
 "subDocument": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.array([Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.document([
     "startTime": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.datetime(2023-01-22 07:39:44 +0000)), 
     "someKey": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("2DFB8488-7D7A-48CD-BCCE-652624BBCBF1")), 
     "coordinates": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.array([Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.double(8.79564924822946)), Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.double(47.498444215458825))])), 
     "subSubDocument": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.array([Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.document([
          "someOtherKey": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("0E425CE8-04C1-458A-87D3-7DE375EDBF50")), 
          "userName": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("ExampleName")), 
          "_id": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("63b3ed0f2e2d45e33bc992d3"))])
)])), 
     "_id": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("1C315817-A9FB-4360-84E9-834083851C33"))]))
])), 
"_id": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("7a7a3b3b-85ab-435d-b1e9-ef13f17cf3c1")), 
"someEvenDifferentProperty": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("A7394D67-4EE1-4490-9E36-99DB87FBCDEA")), 
"example2": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.bool(false))]]
```

This is the Swift `Decodable` object I want to convert the result to:

```swift
class Model: Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Decodable {
    static func == (lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id: String
    var subDocument: SubDocument?
    var example: Double?
    @Published var example2: Bool = false
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case subDocument
        case example
        case example2
    }

    // this is needed because of @Published I believe
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        subDocument = try container.decode(SubDocument.self, forKey: .subDocument)
        example = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .example)
        example2 = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .example2)
    }
```

Then there is a subdocument that looks very similar and contains another `SubSubDocument`, which only contains some `String`s.

P.S. This question was asked after finding out the best way to achieve this would probably be to use a `Codable`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75175460/9739903) for reference.

Comment: Optional values in a Swift dictionary make no sense because `nil` means *no key*. And `Codable` does not support `Any` at all. **All** values in a dictionary **must** conform to `Codable`, period.

Comment: @vadian I assume you were referring to `document["property"]??.doubleValue`? I added the raw data of the response to illustrate why exactly this way of unwrapping was necessary.. If not, could you elaborate your point?

Comment: I do not quite agree with the statement *"Optional values in a Swift dictionary make no sense"* if you are referring to `Dictionary<String, AnyBSON?>`. This is simply how Realm has implemented the `Document`. It's not my choice, it's what is used by this SDK... It is also not the key that is optional, but the value of type AnyBSON

Comment: I don’t know Realm but it seems that it fights the Swift language semantics. If you assign `nil` to a key In a **Swift** dictionary the key will be removed.

Comment: I am mostly concerned about "performance issues due to converting a Document to a Swift Object". As mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175460/performant-conversion-to-swift-object-from-mongodb-graphql-result/75194196?noredirect=1#comment132699431_75194196) that code 'converted' (instantiated) 10,000 documents in about second - and that really has very little to do with Realm. Codable is powerful and adds convenience and tighter code but I am not sure there are any crazy performance benefits.

Comment: @vadian For MongoDB Atlas (and Realm) nil values are represented by null (NSNull in swift) for optionals in the back-end database. e.g. for AnyBSON, null is a valid value. When evaluated, it can return an <optional>nil, so it has to be double unwrapped e.g. `let x = document?["optionalValue"]??.stringValue` to get either the value or an actual nil.